# What's the difference between the HTML width / height attribute and the CSS width / height property on the img element?

Tags: html, css, properties, tags

The HTML `<img>` element can have the **width** / **height** attribute, and it can also have the CSS **width** / **height** properties:

```html
<img src="xxx.img" width="16" height="16"
style="width: 16px; height: 16px"></img>
```

What's the difference between the HTML attribute and CSS property and should they have the same effect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A hot debate about the subject can be found here: [Width attribute for image tag versus CSS](https://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/155362-width-attribute-img-versus-img-style-width)

To sum it up:

> The gain from declaring a width value and an height value (which may not be the original physical dimensions of the image) or from css declarations (like width: [valueX]; height: [valueY];) is that it helps speed up the rendering of the page. The browser knows how much space to allocate a particular area of the page: it will even draw image placeholders on a first draw, a first parsing+rendering of the page. When one does not define any width and height, then the browser has to download the image and then figure out its dimensions, space to allocate and then redraw the page.

This seems to be the most beneficial effect in my opinion.

Comment: Warning, the linked blog post is from 2005 and CSS standards may be different now than then.

Comment: The above comment also suggests there's no difference! Declaring it as an attribute or in the css helps speed up the rendering of the page.

Answer (score 11):

**They have the same effect.**

`<img width="100" height="100" />` has been used for a long time, same with the widht/height properties of say.. an HTML table.

There is no difference whether you specify it on the element itself or within the CSS, though I now prefer using CSS so I can keep the HTML clear and concise.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/N2RgB/1/

I've loaded the same image 4 times, both proportional and non-proportional using HTML attributes **AND** CSS properties.

**There is absolutely NO difference.**

Comment: I heard CSS is being turned standard, and so the <img> attributes might be deprecated sometime.

Comment: And according to my experiments, if the attributes contradict the style, the style wins.  (Firefox, Chrome)

Comment: Well, there is absolutely a difference. Browsers always download HTML first then style sheets, which means you can reserve some width with attribute then apply the correct style later, when you want to pursue user experience.

Comment: One of the difference I've spotted is when you are using lazy loading: https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#images-should-include-dimension-attributes .

Answer (score 5):

When **width** and **height** are used in the `<img>` tag as :

```
<img src="xxx.img" width="25" height="25">
```

then **width** and **height** attributes are called *presentational attributes*.

And when **width** and **height** are used in the `<img>` tag as :

```
<img style="width: 16px; height: 16px">
```

then **width** and **height** are said to be defined using *inline CSS styles*

So we can define **width** and **height** for an `<img>` tag as *presentational attributes* or using *inline CSS styles*, **in both the ways we will get same result.**

But the only difference between defining **width** and **height** for an `<img>` as *presentational attributes* and by using *inline CSS styles* is, defining **width** and **height** as *presentational attributes* is the **weakest way** to define **width** and **height** for `<img>` tag whereas defining **width** and **height** using *inline CSS style* is the **strongest way** of defining **width** and **height** for the `<img>` tag.

So if we define **width** and **height** in both ways (that is as *presentational attributes* and by using *inline CSS styles*) then the definition for **width** and **height** using *inline CSS style* will override the definition of **width** and **height** as *presentational attributes*

So basically *presentational attributes* on `<img>` tag is a good idea but *presentational attributes* are also weak and are usually overridden by *inline CSS styles*

For reference check [this](https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference-between-width-height-in-css-and-width-height-html-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

I made a comparison up at: http://jsfiddle.net/jF8y6/ with 4 different states. The main difference is the way it is used via external stylesheets in terms of the ability to resize images for different stylesheets (desktop, mobile, print, etc) and the flexibility it brings. If you hardcode the sizes then it stops the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_IMG.asp

- I haven't used the image tag in a while for this purpose.
  But there is a difference, the attributes can be relative to the images dimensions, CSS style properties are absolute (either %, px, em...)

Comment: How can you use dimensions relative to the image's dimensions? I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in semantic and general approach rather than in how the rendering will work. :) I personally prefer to concentrate all things like width and heights within CSS classes and avoid to use both attributes like "width" and inline styles like "style='width:100px'", just because it results in nice logical separation - HTML markup tells what should be displayed and CSS rules - how exactly it will look.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a difference...
Check the following code snippet out stolen from: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/button/icons.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Button - Icons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- redefine source of background-image -->
<style>
    .ui-icon { width: 64px; height: 64px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    $("img").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-locked"
        },
        text: false
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img width="32px" height="32px"> <!-- size of img tag -->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
<img src="some_pic.jpg" width="100" />
```

it's height will be auto-size.

and this

```
<img src="some_pic.jpg" style="width:100px" />
```

it's height will not be auto-size.

just try more,and you know the difference

Comment: What's auto-size? Both properties are the same.

Comment: I try it just now.
it's the same.
sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Have you tried it? Setting 1 of the properties in CSS (either width or height) will still make the image resize to fit it's proportions.