# What's the core difference between HTML Style Property vs directly putting the property inside the tags?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was under the impression that

```
<img width="48%" /> (wordpress classic editor will do it this way by default)
```

is the same as

```
<img style="width:48%;" />
```

However, in real-life tests, I'm finding my WordPress theme completely failing with the aforementioned. HTML Style property works, the direct property embed totally gets ignored. So what's going on exactly?

```
<img style="width:48%;" /> does not work (default)
```

```
<img width="48%" /> works
```

I just want to really understand what the difference is between the two ways of adding attributes.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562296/whats-the-difference-between-the-html-width-height-attribute-and-the-css-widt

Comment: When using `width` attribute, it expect a value w/o a unit, and the value is in `pixel`'s, so no, `<img width="48%" />` does **not** work

Comment: What do you mean with `not work (default)`

Comment: @LGSon for html5 this is true, before that you were also allowed to use percentage. And most browsers still support it even in html5 mode for backward compatibility.

Comment: @t.niese True....and today (5 years after its release) I expect we talk about HTML5

Comment: @LGSon yes but saying it does not work is misleading, as it most certainly works for the OP, because browsers still support it. It is just not valid. (the same way as `/>` is not valid for `img`)

Comment: I create an example, https://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/QWWbLzp just to confirm. I think you need to provide more context here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the HTML width / height attribute and the CSS width / height property on the img element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562296/whats-the-difference-between-the-html-width-height-attribute-and-the-css-widt)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the percentage in img tag width attribute it only takes number which is considered as pixel `<img width="48" />` here 48 is in pixels.
But when you use inline CSS or style attribute you can specify values with percentage.

Comment: I think priority is also a difference when there's a collision between these two. Please confirm as I'm not completely sure.

Comment: When you put width attribute both side like as width as an img attribute and also in the style CSS file or as a property the HTML file considered first style CSS width property. The collision never happens...

Comment: I think you should update your answer with it. Also, you could introduce `!important` here.

Comment: @MerajalMaksud why should `!important`  be introduced here? That topic completely unrelated to the question, and `!important` is something you shouldn't use anyway.